# Clicks from Chrome Extension script to (same-origin) dynamically added iframes have no effect

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I’m developing a Chrome Extension for a specific website. The script is injected after page load, the script clicks a button, and an iframe popup is loaded.

**inject.js**

```
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
        document.getElementById(‘aButton’).click();
```

**NOTE**: *Unlike many similar questions on SO*, the resulting iframe is same-origin. It is **NOT** from an external site, and there are no warnings in the inspector. (Also confirmed in Sources tab)

The script waits 3 seconds for the popup to fully load, accesses the iframe’s document object, then clicks on the target – **AND nothing happens**.

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    let doc = document.getElementById('iframeOne');
    let innerDoc = doc.contentDocument ||  doc.contentWindow.document;
    let innerDocElem =  innerDoc.getElementById('innerDocElem');
    innerDocElem.click();
  }, 3000);
```

***What I’ve Tried:***

I’ve set my file’s content scripts to include **all frames**, and since the iframe is of same origin, the wildcard in matches should give the script access to the iframe.

**manifest.json**

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches":  "https://awebsite.com/*" ,
    "js": "src/inject/inject.js" ,
    "allframes": true
  }]
```

I’ve tried using css transforms to move the element to top-left, and then using x,y coordinates to click on the iframe’s buttons

```
  document.elementFromPoint(250, 204).click();
```

I’ve also tried replacing the click() method with a simulated **mouse event** as suggested in these answers:

[How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript)

[JavaScript click() method only works once in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033588/javascript-click-method-only-works-once-in-chrome-extension/15390455)

Comment: Try dispatching the event instead: innerDocElem.dispatchEvent(new doc.contentWindow.Event('click', {bubbles:true})). Or maybe the iframe code wants a mousedown event. I would also debug the [existing event listener in devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atIHE.png).

Comment: Thank you VERY much! The page was listening for a "mousedown" event! I had been trying for days to "click" the element. Thanks again.